# python loop, Pyramid pattern

Tags: python, loops, design-patterns

can anyone help me with this code. It must be done using for and if only.

```
        0
      1 0 1
    2 1 0 1 2
  3 2 1 0 1 2 3
4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4
```

I tired and think every stuff but I dont understand what i am missing. I am having a issue with generating 101, 21012, 3210123, 43211234

here is my code(which is wrong)

```
for i in range (1,6):
    for t in range (i,5):
        print('\t', end="")
    for j in range (0,(2*i-1)):
        print(2*i-1-j, "\t", end="")
    print("")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEMHn.png)

Comment: the formating is disturbed after posting. Please check the image  attached. I

Comment: Please fix formatting. At least for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each row, the numbers start high, then go down to zero, then go up again. Since loops typically only go in one direction, why not use two loops? If you have one loop count from i down to one and then the next one count from 0 up to i, you should get your desired result. Let me know if there's anything you would like for me to clarify about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow `list-comprehension`

```
num = 4
for i in range(num+1):
    j = [str(n) for n in range(i+1)]
    k = list(reversed(j))
    print (' '.join([' '] * (num-i) + k + j[1:]))
```

Output:

```
        0
      1 0 1
    2 1 0 1 2
  3 2 1 0 1 2 3
4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: thats something new. I have not come across list-comprehension till now. I am going to study about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

so here is my final code which run correctly
strong text

```
for i in range (1,6):
    for t in range (i,5):
        print('\t', end="")
    for j in range (0,i):
        print(i-j-1, "\t", end="")
    for k in range (1,i):
        print (k,"\t" ,end="")
    print("")
```

Comment: Try remove `\t` in `j` and `k` print loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different solution using list:

```
n = 4
lizst = [0]
for h in range (1, n+2):
  print("\t"*(n+1-h), end = "")
  [print(e, "", end = "") for e in lizst]
  lizst = [h] + lizst + [h]
  print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Soultion using just for loop.

```
spaces=4
limits=0

for line in range(5):
    for space in range(spaces):
        print(' ',end=' ')
    for limit in range(limits,-1,-1):
        print(limit,end=' ')
    for limit in range(1,limits+1):
        print(limit,end=' ')
    spaces-=1
    limits+=1
    print('\n')
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1d6x.png)